# How to remove the building number and entrance from an address string with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have various address strings that I would like to automatically clean from the building number part, leaving only the street address.

**examples:**

- input:

```
"15A W 131st St, New York, NY 10037, USA"
```

- wanted output:

```
"W 131st St, New York, NY 10037, USA"
```

---

- input:

```
"125 E 145th St, New York, NY 10037, USA"
```

- wanted output:

```
"E 145th St, New York, NY 10037, USA"
```

---

- input:

```
"3 Rue Auguste Bartholdi, 75015 Paris, France"
```

- wanted output:

```
"Rue Auguste Bartholdi, 75015 Paris, France"
```

---

I have tried working with `String.prototype.match()` and the following regex: `/[^0-9\s].+/` which works well to remove numbers but doesn't work if the building has an alphabetic entrance (35A, 20B, etc.). Working with the alphabetic character got me in problems about the rest of the string.

Comment: Is it always going to be the first x characters followed by a space? Maybe you can use `address.replace(/^[^\s]+\s/, '')`. That replaces everything from the start up till the first space.

Comment: How about `str = str.replace(/^\d+\W+/, '');`

Comment: ^\d+\w?\s works with all the 3 sample given above...

Comment: For now i solved it with a different approach: `let newAddress = fullAddress.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");`. This removes anything before the first space char. I'll try your suggestions in a regex playground.

Comment: I think the main issue was that i was trying to select the rest of the address string rather than the beginning of it.

Comment: just another one: `/^\d+[A-z]?\s/`

Comment: https://www.mjt.me.uk/posts/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-addresses/

Comment: @AuxTaco oh boy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My main problem was that I was trying to match the rest of the string and keep it with `String.match()` instead of targeting the beginning of the string and deleting it with `String.replace()`.

A few regex expressions that solve when using this `String.replace()`attitude:

```
address.replace(/^\d+[A-z]?\s/, '')
address.replace(/^[^\s]+\s/, '')
```

Another solution would be to target the white spaces by using the `String.split()` method. This means converting to array of words, deleting the first word, and joining the array into a new clean string.

code:

```
let newAddress = fullAddress.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution IMO opinion is using regex

```
[^\s]+\s+
```

Reason is better than `split splice and join` approach is you're having a n overhead first change  string to array and than after manipulation again change it back to string, whereas replace just does the manipulation no conversion from string to array and than again back to string

```js
let strs = ["15A W 131st St, New York, NY 10037, USA","125 E 145th St, New York, NY 10037, USA","3 Rue Auguste Bartholdi, 75015 Paris, France"]

strs.forEach(str=>{
  let final = str.replace(/^[^\s]+\s+/,'')
  console.log(final)
})
```